# What are the potential pitfalls of running a VPN business?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, crime

Disclaimer: I am pretty noob on this issue. I made my research but could not find satisfying information.

The question is pretty straightforward but I still want to elaborate a little bit more:

Consider running a VPN business under following circumstances:

- You don't keep any kind of log.
- Your service is available to all countries.

If some malicious person uses your service and commit some kind of criminal activity, do they still put the blame on you?

Comment: It might be good to look at say, ExpressVPN or Tunnelbears Terms and Agreements and even lookup current suits to see what the pitfalls could be. learn from those that have already done.

Comment: @Chenmunka what if a terrorist uses my service (i.e Paris bombings) just before they commit a criminal activity? or a pedophile uses to download child porn? How can I defend myself when I don't keep any log?

Comment: @EkremDoğan  I think you should ask this question on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I second @user902383. This question concerns cyberlaw, not information security. I vote 'off-topic' for this question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely legal question and thus off-topic here. Try law.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should first look into common sense issue.

VPN services providers are no different than ANY other Internet services. There is waiver clause against all sort of illegal activities. For example,  [Tunnelbear Terms and conditions](https://www.tunnelbear.com/tos) mentioned clearly on illegal activities.

Imagine you try to do a pen-testing over VPN, e.g. port scan, syn-flood. Those activities may be stopped ASAP from the exit point. No sane VPN provider will initiate connection blindly that risk their server blacklisted for such reason. They have rights to terminated the malicious services immediately, as mentioned in their ToS.